# PHP MYSQL INSERT not working?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

```
<?php
require "dbconnect.php";
$resultno = mysql_query("SELECT `time` FROM syslog");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultno))
 {
$mysqltime = $row['time'];
$timestamp = strtotime($mysqltime);
$update = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
echo $update;
 }
$mysqlupdate = mysql_query("INSERT INTO (`datetime`) VALUES ('$update')");
```

The results stream by but no updates? I must be missing something...

Thanks

Comment: $mysqlupdate = mysql_query("INSERT INTO syslog (`datetime`) VALUES ('$update')");

Still no luck?  Hmm..

Comment: Could you tell me what kind of type do you have for datetime column in your mysql table ?

Comment: I see the problem, I am adding just new rows and not add to the end of each row...

Comment: Do you have time and datetime both fields in syslog table ? Brief about your table structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have missed the table name in insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (`datetime`) VALUES ('$update')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a table-name after INTO in the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look at the [UPDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp) command instead of insert. If you are looking to update, you shouldn't be using insert.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what @Paulraj correctly pointed out, you are also passing your php variable as a string.

It should be `"INSERT INTO (`datetime`) VALUES ('" . $update . "')"`